# How Can I search document of cloudant geospacial index with cloudant-client

Tags: java, geospatial, cloudant

I am trying to search documents using geospatial index of cloudant.
Besides I have been using cloudant java client as below.
But I cannot find the way or samples to search documents.
Please Help Me!!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the geospacial index.

```
_design/eventgeo
indexname:st_index

function (doc) {
if (doc.geometry && doc.geometry.coordinates) {
    st_index(doc.geometry);
  }
}
```

Im trying to search the documents as below. but I get error:

> Exception message:404 Object Not Found at
>   https://??????.cloudant.com:443/events/_design/eventgeo/_search/_geo?limit=10&include_docs=true&q=lat:150.78688%20and%20lon:38.67915%20and%20radius:10000%20and%20relation:contains%20and%20include_docs:true.
>   Error: not_found. Reason: _geo not found..

```
List<Event> events = this.database.search("eventgeo/_geo/st_index").limit(10).includeDocs(true)
        .query("lat:" + latitude + " and lon:" + longitude + " and radius:" + 10000 + " and relation:contains"
                + " and include_docs:true", Event.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Cloudant documentation for geospatial queries:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant-geo.html#cloudant-nosql-db-geospatial

You appear to be using the search API endpoint:

`_design/eventgeo/_search/_geo`

I believe you want to use the geospatial indexing API endpoint instead:

`_design/eventgeo/_geo/geoidx`